# Какую книгу и курс порекомендуете

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Какие книги и видеокурсы порекомендуете начинающему веб-разработчику. Книги по таким языкам, как HTML5 и CSS3, PHP, Jscript...

Comment: Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL и JavaScript. Робин Никсон. Видеокурсы мне больше всего понравились от Teamtreehouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Книги предпочитаю издательства O'Reilly (там есть и по javascript и по html и по php).
По PHP очень хорошая книга от O'Reilly PHP Рецепты Программирования Дэвид Скляр. Книга полезна как для начинающих, так и для продвинутых т.к. вся книга это набор "рецептов".

Что касается изучения, то рекомендую просто начать создавать сайт (желательно на хорошем хостинге например godaddy). Зачем? Потому что будет очень хорошо запоминаться на практике, когда проблемы написания кода появляются. Просто невозможно всё сразу в голову поместить, нужно поэтапно.
По HTML http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Что касается HTML то советую просто разобраться с  тэгами т.к. "они везде", далее изучать bootstrap.
http://getbootstrap.com/
и jquery (рекомендую начать с селекторов, они самые простые)
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Что касается джаваскрипта, то это https://learn.javascript.ru/
На сайте очень удобно учить.

Answer (score 0):

Для веб-программирования требуется знать основы html и css, после этого можно начинать изучать PHP и javascript.

Для изучения основ веб-программирования не обязательно приобретать книги, существует множество статей, видео и книг в рунете.

Рекомендую сайт htmlbook:http://htmlbook.ru/ в котором есть всё для начинающего веб разработчика. Основы:http://htmlbook.ru/content/osnovy-html

Я изучал html и css с помощью других сайтов, скачивал чужые сайты с помощью программы HTTrack разбирал и смотрел как всё работает. Уже через пол года я создал свой сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Lynda.com
Infiniteskills.com

Очень хорошие ресурсы с видеоуроками, есть градация по уровням знаний. Сам начинал с них.

Есть ещё много каналов на YouTube...

P.S. Не считайте за рекламу)